# Differential Entropy Bounds in Measure Theory

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, entropy

Suppose $\mu$ is a probability measure (on a set, say $\mathbb{R}^n$), and $f\geq 0$ is a function that integrates to $1$ with respect to $\mu$. Then, set $S(f)$ to be the limit $$S(f)=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int f\log(f+\epsilon)\ d\mu.$$

(a) Assuming that $S(f)$ can be infinite, show that $S(f)$ exists, and that $S(f)\geq 0$.

(b) Assuming that $h$ is a bounded real function, prove the following inequality: $$\int hf\ d\mu-S(f)\leq \log({\int e^h\ d\mu}).$$
I tried to solve the problem but I'm not sure if they are right. Here are the outlines of the solution:

a) We use the Dominated Convergence Theorem. As $ \epsilon \to 0^+ $, $ f \log(f + \epsilon) $ converges pointwise to $ f \log f $. Since $ f \geq 0 $ and integrates to 1, we can use the function $ h = f$ as the dominating function. $ f \log(f + \epsilon) $ is bounded above by $ f $ and $ \int f d\mu = 1 $, so $ f $ is integrable. Finally, by Dominated Convergence Theorem, $ S(f) $ exists.

b) We use the inequality $ e^x \geq x + 1 $, which is true for all real $ x $. We have:
$$ e^h \geq h + 1 \implies f e^h \geq hf + f \implies \int f e^h\ d\mu \geq \int hf\ d\mu + \int f\ d\mu. $$
Since $ \int f\ d\mu = 1 $:
$$ \int f e^h\ d\mu \geq \int hf\ d\mu + 1 \implies \log\left(\int f e^h\ d\mu\right) \geq \log\left(\int hf\ d\mu + 1\right) $$
From the definition of $ S(f) $, we have $ S(f) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \int f \log(f + \epsilon)\ d\mu $. Note that $ \int hf\ d\mu $ is essentially the integral of $ f \log(f) $ with $ h$ acting as a modifier. Thus,
$$ \int hf\ d\mu - S(f) \leq \log\left(\int e^h\ d\mu\right). $$

Comment: IMO it's better to call this relative entropy (or KL divergence), following standard terminology in information theory. In any case, your argument for $a)$ doesn't make sense to me: if $f > 1$ somewhere, then $f \not > f \log f$, so I don't see why $f$ is a dominating function. For $b)$, "$\int hf \mathrm{d}\mu$ is essentially the integral of $f \log f$ with $h$ acting as a modifier" makes zero sense to me. What is a modifier? How does it lead to the conclusion?

Comment: Also, note that $S(f)$ can be $\infty,$ so the "exists" terminology needs to be clarified: consider $\mathrm{d}\mu = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2} \mathrm{d}x, f  = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \frac{e^{x^2/2}}{1+x^2}$. Here $f$ grows very quickly, and dominates any mollifying action of the $+\varepsilon$, so $ \int f \log ( f+ \varepsilon) $ is dominated by a tail of the form $\int_{|x| > \xi(\varepsilon)} \frac{x^2/2 - \log(1+x^2)}{1+x^2} = \infty$.

Comment: Finally, these results are standard: $S(f) \ge 0$ is called Gibbs' inequality, and b) is a consequence of the Donsker-Varadhan representation of relative entropy. Both have been well explored on this website, searching should yield proofs to refer to. In particular, and as hints, the argument for a) must employ some convexity properties, and for b) requires using a tilt, and then exploiting Gibbs' inequality.

Comment: Thank you! That was really useful!

Comment: I'm assuming that part (a) uses Jensen's inequality